# MySQL Prepared Statement optimization

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently still learning MySQL And prepared statements and i was wondering if this code i've written is the most efficient way.

The process...

1. There's a query that checks a table called 'websites' for a field called 'websites_pagecount'

The same query then increments the field by 1. *(I haven't done this is the database using auto-increment because there will be more than one row with the same number)*

2. Theres a query that then runs and grabs the new number
3. Then another query runs and creates a row in a table called 'pages' and sets the new 'pagecount' number in to the 'page_id' field (Again, i haven't used auto-increment on this as there will be more than one row with the same number)

However it all seems a bit 'cumbersome'.. this is the code ive got.

```
        $mysql['stmt'] = $mysql['conn']->prepare("UPDATE websites SET website_pagecount=website_pagecount+? WHERE website_domain=?");
        $mysql['stmt']->bind_param("is", $a = 1, $website['website_id']);
        $result = $mysql['stmt']->execute();
        $mysql['stmt']->close();


        $mysql['stmt'] = $mysql['conn']->prepare("SELECT website_pagecount FROM websites WHERE website_domain = ?");
        $mysql['stmt']->bind_param("s", $website['website_id']);
        $result = $mysql['stmt']->execute();
        //GET ROWS
        $result = $mysql['stmt']->get_result();
        $pagecount = $result->fetch_assoc();
        $mysql['stmt']->close();


        $mysql['stmt'] = $mysql['conn']->prepare("INSERT INTO pages (page_id,page_parent, page_title, page_description,page_keywords, website_id, page_layout) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        $mysql['stmt']->bind_param("issssss",$pagecount['website_pagecount'],$item['parentpage'],$item['pagetitle'],$item['pagedescription'],$item['pagekeywords'],$website['website_id'],$item['pagelayout'] );
        $result = $mysql['stmt']->execute();
        $mysql['stmt']->close();
```

Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This sounds like it'd be better on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/. Code is working just looking for a review right?

Comment: Ah ok ill move it over - didnt even know code review exsisted! Thanks.